# How to determine xdy dice roll from a sample?

Tags: dice

I'm playing an RPG based on DnD xdy dice damage rolls, where x is the number of dice rolled and y is the number of sides on each die. So, normal double-sixes dice people are familiar with would be 2d6. These dice rolls generate a discrete distribution, which approaches a normal distribution as more dice are added.

I would like to know if there exists a statistical method which, when given a sample of damage output (where xdy is unknown), will allow me to match it to some xdy roll.

So, given say 1000 hits, I find I have a range of 3-18, a mean of 10.71, and a standard deviation of ~3.01. This looks pretty close to a 3d6, but is there some statistical test I can run to generate some probability estimate, confidence interval/level, etc?

I realize that certain heuristic methods can help to some extent, such as if I have a "3" in my sample, then the "x" in xdy must be less than or equal to 3. Similarly, knowing the mean and St.Dev can often give good hints. However, the difference between say a 5d6 and 6d5 is fairly small, and a very large sample might still have "6" as the lowest observed sample value for a 5d6 roll.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. For example, what is 3d6 or xdy?

Comment: What values of $y$ can we assume, i.e., what dice are allowed? Only the standard d4, d6, d8, d10, d12, d20, or also some nonstandard dice?

Comment: Any integer values could be used, so it would not be limited to "standard" gaming dice, but could take any values such as xd7.

Comment: Looks like solved in Math already http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68879/formula-for-working-out-the-number-of-dice-combinations-resulting-in-a-given-val.  Well, this will get you a histogram of possibilities.  Normalize this by $y^x$ and then you have a probability distribution.  Then calculate whatever you want

Comment: Sure, I can already calculate a distribution for a given known xdy, so for 2d6 I know the probabilities are 1/36, 2/36, and so on for 2, 3, etc. I'm trying to basically work backwards from a sample, where the the xdy are unknown, to solve for x and y, or at least to give some statistical information about what x and y are likely to be.

Comment: Ah, ok I misunderstood.  I'll have to think about that one a little more... Seems you won't be able to get a unique answer as Dice rolls are non-gaussian distributions and only considering the mean and std ignores all higher moments.  Still might be able to get a good approximation.

Comment: Are you limiting this a single type of dice or could there be multiple types?  E.g. 1d10 + 2d4?  also has a range of 3-18

Comment: Good question. I'm limiting this to a single type of die, should have specified.

Comment: Then the range uniquely describes it.  the lower limit of the range is the number of dice and the upper limit/lower limit is the type.

Comment: Well, yes, but again I'm only dealing with a sample. For a simple xdy like 2d4 where there are only 16 combinations, a hundred or so rolls is highly likely to include the upper and lower limit. For something like a 6d5, where there are some 15625 combinations, the chance of seeing a 6 or a 30 is very small unless the sample size is large enough. In most cases I will only be able to take a couple thousand samples in a reasonable time frame, and I don't know what the actual xdy is beforehand.

Comment: @GregPetersen: a sample from 2d4 could in principle also come from 2d6 or 2d8. The question is how to detect that $y=4$, rather than $y=6$ or $y=8$.

Comment: Thanks @StephanKolassa.  I like your solution but is still based on fitting a distribution rather than using range, mean, and std is it not?  Regardless, I think it is a short step to modify your answer unless the degeneracy gets to a point where you can't distinguish between close situations (e.g. 30d8 and 24d10)

Comment: @GregPetersen: yes indeed. The OP specified "given a sample of damage output", which I took to mean that I could work with the entire empirical distribution of the observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is.

Let's assume that we could see $k$ different types of dice with $Y=\{y_1, \dots, y_k\}$ pips. The "classical" D&D dice would yield $Y=\{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100\}$, but anything else could be made to work as below. Let  $|Y|$ denote the number of different possible dice.

Assume that the minimum observed roll is $m$ and the maximum is $M$. This gives us bounds on the possible number of dice involved: we must have

$$m\leq x\leq M.$$

Now, simulate a large number of rolls from each remaining candidate xdy (by the formula above, there are $(M-m+1)\times |Y|$ different candidates). This large number can be larger than the number of original observations. In each case, create a histogram of total outcomes.

Finally, compare these density histograms to the histogram of the original observations. (We work with the densities, not the frequencies, so we can use different numbers of simulations from the original number of observations.) The [earth mover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover's_distance) gives you a notion of distance between histograms. The simulation-based histogram with the lowest earth mover's distance to your original observation histogram is most consistent with your observations.

Here is some R code. We simulate 1000 rolls of 3d6 and use the standard D&D dice as candidates $Y$.

```
set.seed(1)
obs <- rowSums(matrix(ceiling(runif(3000,0,6)),nrow=1000))
candidates.y <- c(4,6,8,10,12,20,100)   # standard D&D dice

breaks <- c(seq(.5,max(obs)+.5,by=1),max(obs)*max(candidates.y))
hist.obs <- hist(obs,breaks=breaks,freq=FALSE)

candidates.x <- 1:max(obs)

n.sims <- 1000

library(emdist)
emd.dist <- matrix(NA,nrow=length(candidates.x),ncol=length(candidates.y),
    dimnames=list(candidates.x,candidates.y))
for ( ii in seq_along(candidates.x) ) {
    for ( jj in seq_along(candidates.y) ) {
        set.seed(1) # for replicability
        obs.sim <- rowSums(matrix(ceiling(
            runif(candidates.x[ii]*n.sims,0,candidates.y[jj])),
          nrow=n.sims))
        hist.sim <- hist(obs.sim,breaks=breaks,plot=FALSE)
        emd.dist[ii,jj] <- emd2d(matrix(hist.obs$density,nrow=1),
          matrix(hist.sim$density,nrow=1))
    }
}
emd.dist
```

Output:

```
           4         6         8        10         12        20        100
1  7.9029999 6.8909998 5.8920002 4.8950000 3.88700008 1.9228243 0.39887184
2  5.4299998 3.4460001 1.4499999 0.8147613 1.08018708 0.8099990 0.04417419
3  2.9579999 0.0000000 1.8063331 1.9216927 1.61559486 0.2684011 0.35928789
4  0.6180000 2.4049284 2.2750988 1.3528987 0.71173453 0.2177625 1.00000000
5  1.9768735 2.8317218 1.7545075 0.5033562 0.17459151 0.1226299 1.00000000
6  3.4169219 1.9913402 0.4674550 0.1918677 0.05264558 1.0000000 1.00000000
7  3.3924465 0.9393466 0.2968451 0.1572183 0.21881166 1.0000000 1.00000000
8  2.6134274 0.3687483 0.1226299 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
9  1.5483801 0.3894975 0.3592879 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
10 0.3270817 0.2188117 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
11 0.1052912 0.3592879 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
12 0.3592879 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
13 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
14 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
15 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
16 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
17 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
18 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
```

And look, the 3d6 in fact does have the simulated histogram with the lowest distance from your observations' histogram. Hurray!

A couple of comments:

- This works better if you have "many" observations. With few observations, you get a lot of noise, and many different simulated histograms are consistent with your noisy data.
- Of course, the larger your candidate set $Y$, the lower your chance will be of getting the true values.
- If the true $y$ is not in $Y$, you will at least get something "close to it".
- The formally-statistically-correct treatment would be a Bayesian one, putting equal prior probabilities on all possible $x$ and $y\in Y$, then calculating or simulating draws and deriving posterior probabilities on pairs $(x,y)$. Yes, this can be done rigorously. Anyone want to have a go?

Comment: Thanks Stephan! While I agree it would be nice to have a formal treatment of the problem, this certainly will do a fantastic job. This is my first post, so I appreciate your patience while I had to modify the question and provide more clarity.

Comment: You are welcome. And thank you for being responsive and engaging in a discussion - too many first posters never respond to requests for clarification. And thanks for setting me a nice little problem for an evening's entertainment!

Comment: Looking deeper at it, I am uncertain about the following inequality:
$$m\leq x\leq \frac{M}{\min Y}.$$
If the "real" xdy is 3d6, and I have a sample min/max of m=4 and M=17, it looks like it breaks down. Am I missing something?

Comment: Good point. My bad .The most we can say is that *we cannot have more than $M$ dice*, i.e., $x\leq M$. I changed my post, sorry about that. Ironically enough, the code was correct about this. And for the lower bound on $x$, wait...

Comment: ... yes, $m$ does not tell us *anything* about the lower bound - we could simply have 1d$M$, so $x=1$ is certainly possible. Let me edit.

Comment: (Deleted my comment by mistake, because I thought I had misunderstood you. I'm off to bed now, seems like that's the best course of action. Will look back in here in the next couple of days.)